# Supervisord: Can supervisord monitor remote processes

Tags: python, supervisord

Can supervisord be used to start remote processes, monitor and manage the processes?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, but I doubt it - the [Features list](http://supervisord.org/introduction.html#features) says:

> You can configure Supervisor to provide a local or remote command line
>   and web interface.

Which means you can certainly control *supervisord* remotely, but there must be a copy of `supervisord` on the same machine as the controlled processes.

Comment: I have 4 supervisord's running on 4 servers, how can I manage the supervisord's from 1 web interface ?

Comment: @SanthoshS, I don't know (never used the web interface), but suspect you would have to address them separately in the web browser. I.e, `http://machine1.com:1234/supervisord`, `machine2`, etc (for however *supervisord* is accessed). If that isn't what you want, might be worth making this a separate new question.